# how to avoid draft creation in office 365?

Tags: javascript, office365

In Compose Mode, I am using below code to get appointment id of existing booking, But I want to skip this code of creating new appointment id for new appointment. Is this possible using some condition to skip this logic?

```
var itemId = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
   if (itemId === null || itemId == undefined) {
     Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function(result){
        itemId = result.value;
     });
   }
```

Comment: hm, remove `if` part?

Comment: then how would I get appointment id for existing booking?

Comment: What do you think first line of your code does?

Comment: @Lashane, both the cases (new and existing appointments) "itemId" value is undefined.

Comment: Microsoft has updated the functionality, now it won't send email to attendees for new appointment and Introduced new bug, now it sends email on existing appointment (by clicking on add-in) calling saveAsync function it sends email to all attendees.